# Selenium: Save and Load LocalStorage to/from File

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm currently writing a script in python to tell me how many unread messages I have in WhatsApp. 
To get the count of unread messages selenium opens [web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com) however I have to authenticate every time. I found out that WhatsApp saves the data to authenticate in the LocalStorage so I'm trying to figure out how I can save the contents from `LocalStorage` to a file and then later read from it and set all the keys.

I tried:

```
localStorage = driver.execute_script('return window.localStorage;')
print(localStorage)
```

but when I do that my terminal running the script just crashes.

Comment: Create a new user profile on your browser, activate it and login to `web.whatsapp.com` using the newly created profile, close the browser. Run the python script and initiate the `webdriver` using the new profile and you should be logged in.

Comment: @PedroLobito Okay, that would work. Is there a way to create a new Firefox profile with Python because? I know I could do it by hand, but I might want to share it when I'm don't and make it easier for people to use it. I googled but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, If it helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new user profile on your browser, activate it and login to `web.whatsapp.com` using the newly created profile, close the browser. Run the python script and initiate the webdriver using the new profile and you should still be logged in, i.e.:

---

The example below is for Firefox and `web.whatsapp.com`, but the general concept can be used on other browsers and websites.

1 - Type `about:profiles` on the browser url box an press enter
2 - Click `Create a New Profile`

[image]

3 - Choose a `name` and `folder` for the new profile (take note of the profile location), in this case : `d:\ff_profiles\selenium_user`

[image]

4 - Activate the new browser profile

[image]

5 - Login to any website that you want to skip the login process on selenium, in this case,  `web.whatsapp.com`

6 - Once you've logged in successfully (after scanning the QR code) close the browser

7 - Using the profile on your script

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('d:\\ff_profiles\\selenium_user') 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
# you should still be logged in.
```